# Anaconda installer not working - Windows 10

Tags: cmd, anaconda, windows-10, python-3.7, miniconda

I have installed the Anaconda 3 in my windows 10 and it has not installed the Scripts folder and the Anaconda Prompt or Navigator applications.

I have come here and in other sources for an answer and tried to reinstall, use the cmd as adm to install with the conda commands, but the system does not recognize the conda command. I have seen answers with the Scripts folder, but it was not installed.

I have also seen answers advising me to install miniconda and then update to anaconda, but again, miniconda has the same problem as anaconda: no scripts folder, no recognition of the conda command.

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Dear all who may have had the same problem, what worked for me was to install the 32-bit version, *I had heard it was more stable*.

I did not have to restart Windows after installing this version, It was already there, Anaconda Prompt and Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I work on a hp Probook with windows 10 and the problem was that the application hp Sure Sense Installer block the installation of anaconda. After uninstalling the hp Sure Sense Installer application and reinstalling anaconda, everything works fine !